# show alternate colors while doing datagrouping of area chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am new to javascript and so to highcharts. i am stuck in a task for long time.
I have created a highstock chart using highchart API. i am getting data using ajax call and display  it in highstock chart. All works fine up till here. My page has option to recreate the chart with showing data in weekly, monthly and quarterly form. For this purpose i used datagrouping on my area chart and here the problem comes up.Now what i want is if user select, say weekly period, then all alternate weekly period areas should have opposite colors, for example, if 1st is dark grey then 2nd should be light grey and then 3rd again dark grey and so on. 
2nd thing i want gaps between every group data. 
Note that i have multiple series in the chart.
Is there any way to do this. Can any one please help me.

here is my code

```
  function line_chart() {
            $.getJSON('http://<?php echo $location; ?>/js/highcharts/server_processing/issuer/tbldailyprice2.php?' + ticker, function (data) {
                // Create the chatu b ajanrt
                mychart = $('#container2').highcharts('StockChart', {
                    chart: {
                        events: {
                            load: function () {
                                chart = this;
                                if (period_name == 'default') {
                                    chart.series[0].update({
                                        dataGrouping: {forced: false,
                                            enabled: false,
                                            approximation: '',
                                            units: [['day', [1]]],
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else if (period_name == 'Quarterly') {
                                    chart.series[0].update({
//                                        stacking: 'percent',
                                        enableMouseTracking: true,
                                        tooltip: {
                                            enabled: true
                                        },
                                        name: 'Periods',
                                        type: 'area' ,
                                        dataGrouping: {forced: true,
                                            approximation: 'sum',
                                            enabled: true,
                                            units: [['month', [3]]],
                                        },
                                    });
                                } else
                                if (period_name == 'Monthly') {
                                    chart.series[0].update({
//                                        stacking: 'percent',
                                        enableMouseTracking: true,
                                        tooltip: {
                                            enabled: true
                                        },
                                        name: 'Periods',
                                        type: 'area' ,
                                        dataGrouping: {
                                            approximation: 'sum',
                                            forced: true,
                                            enabled: true,
                                            units: [['month', [1]]],
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else
                                if (period_name == 'Weekly') {
                                    chart.series[0].update({
//                                        stacking: 'percent',
                                        enableMouseTracking: true,
                                        tooltip: {
                                            enabled: true
                                        },
                                        name: 'Periods',
                                        type: 'area' ,
                                        approximation: 'sum',
                                        dataGrouping: {forced: true,
                                            enabled: true,
                                            approximation: 'sum',
                                            units: [['week', [1]]],
                                        }

                                    });
                                }
                                $.getJSON('http://' + closeperiodsurl, function (newdata) {
                                    chart.series[0].setData(newdata);
                                    // series.setData(data);
                                });
                                $.getJSON('http://' + buys_sells_url + "&type=buy", function (newdata) {
                                    chart.series[2].setData(newdata);
                                    // series.setData(data);
                                });
                                $.getJSON('http://' + buys_sells_url + "&type=sell", function (newdata) {
                                    chart.series[3].setData(newdata);
                                    // series.setData(data);
                                });
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 1
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
                    }, tooltip: {
                        shared: false,
                        crosshairs: true,
                        formatter: function () {
                            var rV = null;
                            var symbol = '$';
                            var color;
                            var company = "?c=<?php echo $_REQUEST["c"] ?>";
                            var ticker_id = "&t=<?php echo $_REQUEST["t"] ?>";
                            if (this.series.name == 'Buy' || this.series.name == 'Sell' || this.series.name == 'Periods') {
                                var date = "&date=" + this.x;
                                if (this.series.name == 'Buy') {
                                    color = '#0000FF';
                                } else if (this.series.name == 'Sell') {
                                    color = '#FF0000';
                                }
                                $.ajax({
                                    //dataType: "json",
                                    url: '../js/highcharts/server_processing/issuer/trade_summary.php' + company + ticker_id + date,
                                    async: false, // this will stall the tooltip
                                    success: function (ajax) {
                                        rV = ajax;
                                        // converting currency values to symbols
                                        var chek = rV.search("EUR");
                                        var chek1 = rV.search("GBP");
                                        var chek_minus = rV.search("-");
                                        if (chek != -1) {
                                            symbol = '\u00A3';
                                            rV = rV.replace("EUR", "\u00A3");
                                        } else if (chek1 != -1) {
                                            rV = rV.replace("GBP", "\u20AC");
                                            symbol = '\u20AC';
                                        }
                                        var split_text = rV.split('<br/>');
                                        // changing the color of last row of tooltip for +ve and _ve values of net trades
                                        if (chek_minus == -1) {
                                            rV = split_text[0] + '<br/><span style="color:' + color + '">' + split_text[1] + '</span>';
                                        } else {
                                            rV = split_text[0] + '<br/><span style="color:#ff0000">' + split_text[1] + '</span>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            if (this.series.name == 'Periods') {
                                var date = "&date=" + this.x;
                                var transactions = '';
                                $.ajax({
                                    //dataType: "json",
                                    url: 'http://' + closeperiodsurl + date + '&action=hover',
                                    async: false, // this will stall the tooltip
                                    success: function (ajax) {
                                        transactions = ajax;
                                    }
                                });
                                var period_format = '';
                                if (period_name == 'Quarterly') {
                                    period_format = period_name;
                                    var s = '';
                                    if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Jan') {
                                        s = s + "1st Quarter"
                                    }
                                    if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Apr') {
                                        s = s + "2nd Quarter"
                                    }
                                    if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Jul') {
                                        s = s + "3rd Quarter"
                                    }
                                    if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Oct') {
                                        s = s + "4th Quarter"
                                    }
                                    period_format = s + " " + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.x);
                                } else if (period_name == 'Monthly') {
                                    period_format = Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %Y', new Date(this.x));
                                } else if (period_name = 'Weekly') {
                                    var s = '';
                                    if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.x) >= 1 && Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.x) <= 7) {
                                        s = s + "1st Week"
                                    }
                                    if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.x) >= 8 && Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.x) <= 14) {
                                        s = s + "2nd Week"
                                    }
                                    if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.x) >= 15 && Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.x) <= 21) {
                                        s = s + "3rd Week"
                                    }
                                    if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.x) >= 22 && Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.x) <= 28) {
                                        s = s + "4th Week"
                                    }
                                    if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.x) >= 29 && Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.x) <= 31) {
                                        s = s + "5th Week"
                                    }
                                    period_format = s + " " + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %Y', this.x);
                                }
                                return period_format + "<br/>" + transactions + "<br/>" + symbol + numberWithCommas(this.y) + " Repurchased";
                            } else
                                return (Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', new Date(this.x)) == '1') ? Highcharts.dateFormat('%est %b %Y', new Date(this.x)) : ((Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', new Date(this.x)) == '2') ? Highcharts.dateFormat('%end %b %Y', new Date(this.x)) : ((Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', new Date(this.x)) == '3') ? Highcharts.dateFormat('%erd %b %Y', new Date(this.x)) : Highcharts.dateFormat('%eth %b %Y', new Date(this.x)))) + '<br/>' +
                                        (this.series.name == 'Buy' || this.series.name == 'Sell' ? rV : '');
                        },
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        lineColor: '#000',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        type: 'datetime',
                        maxZoom: 3600000 * 24 * 30 * 2, // roughly 2 months
                        //maxZoom: 28 * 24 * 3600000, // fourteen days
                        maxPadding: 0.05
                    },
                    // Y AXIS - PRIMARY
                    yAxis: [{
                            //minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                            lineColor: '#000',
                            // max: 1000,
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            tickWidth: 1,
                            tickColor: '#000',
                            minPadding: 0.2,
                            maxPadding: 0.2,
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            }
                        }, {// Secondary yAxis
                            title: {
                                text: 'Close Periods',
                                max: 0.4,
                                min: 0.3,
                                gridLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                gridLineWidth: 0,
                            },
                            //labels:false,
                            opposite: true
                        }],
                    navigator: {
                        // hides the plotted line at bottom of the chart
                        series: {
                            lineWidth: 0,
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
    series:{  pointPadding:0,
                groupPadding:5,
                pointWidth:25
    }
},
                    series: [{
                            // CLOSE PERIOD
                            name: '',
                            maxPointWidth: 90,
                            color: '#c0c0c0',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            type: close_period_chart_type,
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            shadow: false,
                            fillOpacity: '0.85',
                            data: [],
                            dataGrouping: {
                                approximation: '',
                                enabled: false,
                                forced: false,
                                units: [['month', [1]]],
                            },

                        }, {
                            name: 'AAPL',
                            data: data,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals: 2,
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }, {
                            //BUYS
                            name: 'Buy',
                            //unit: '%',
                            color: '#ffffff',
                            type: 'scatter',
                            enableMouseTracking: true,
                            marker: {
                                symbol: 'url(../img/highcharts/buy.png)'
                            },
                            data: [],
                            tooltip: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }, {
                            // SELLS
                            name: 'Sell',
                            //unit: '%',
                            color: '#ffffff',
                            type: 'scatter',
                            // enableMouseTracking: true,
                            marker: {
                                symbol: 'url(../img/highcharts/sell.png)'
                            },
                            data: [],
                        }],
                });
            });
        }
```